# Javascript ES6 modules name resolution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm absolutely sure, that I'm asking a silly question, but I really do not understand how this line of code works

```
import React from 'react';
```

My question: who and where searches for `'react'` name?

For example, [this site](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html) tells me, that for `module-name` I should use relative of absolute path, e.g

```
import React from './react';
```

or

```
import React from '/home/user/react';
```

I thought that `'react'` is same as `'./react'` but I've created ReactJS applcation via `create-react-app` command and didn't find any file named `react.js` in application folder.

So, obviously there is some tool or rule by which module name has been resolved to a proper file, but I cannot find proper documentation about this.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together

Comment: @Evert, thanks. Am I understand right, that npm resolve this line of code to a proper path to module during build, using information from package.json?

Comment: No, this is not a build-time thing. It's runtime. `package.json` is used during resolution, but only to parse the `main` field I think.

Comment: As far as I could conclude from the site I've meant in question, ES6 modules are statically included and their content is known on build stage, so I didn' clearly understand motivation of runtime loading of modules.

Comment: Node.js does not have a build stage really. Javascript is an interpreted language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Import statements are importing packages by name from the `node_modules` directory in your app**, which is where they're saved when you run an installation command such as `npm install` or `yarn` inside your app.

When you write:

```js
import React from 'react';
```

As far as you're concerned, it's as if you'd written:

```js
import React from './node_modules/react/index.js';
```

Importing by package name means you don't have to be aware of how a given package is structured or where your `node_modules` directory is relative to your javascript file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As far as I understood, this is not a part of ES6 standard and just and implementaion defined thing for `npm`? So, now I'm not sure about how JS IDEs work. Do they rely on some "well-known' paths and resolve these names by themselfs?

Comment: `node_modules` is hardcoded into `node` core, and to any modern IDE, that's a "well known" path. The `npm` package format also specifies that every directory inside `node_modules` will contain a `package.json` file, which among other things establishes the `name` of the package and which file inside serves as the entry point.